# Spring - JPA query for second level entity on Table Per Class

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Querying for a second level entity in Spring with JPA and there is no error, the web page sits on spinning wheel loading, and the debugger window shows the query, but no error.

The top-level entity is `Health Check`, and I am trying to retrieve a list of entities extended by `Task` with it.

**Health Check**

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="HEALTH_CHECK")
public class HealthCheck {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long healthCheckid;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    private Bird bird;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="healthCheck")
    private List<Task> tasks;

}
```

**Task**

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TASK_TYPE")
@Table(name="TASK")
public class Task {

    @Id
    private Long taskId;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private HealthCheck healthCheck;

}
```

Various entities extend `Task` like `PIT`, `MEM` and `XMIT` - only `PIT` shown here for berevity:

**PIT**

```java
@Entity
public class PIT extends Task {

    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotEmpty(message = "Name must not be null or empty")
    private String code;

    @JoinColumn(name ="date_instered")
    private LocalDate dateInserted;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    private HealthCheck healthCheck;

    @Lob
    private String comment;    
}
```

**NB** PIT is one of four extended classes using Task. I have tried to query for a `Health Check` with all associated tasks in the following query, but this just gives `Health Check` details.

```java
public interface HealthCheckRepository extends JpaRepository<HealthCheck, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT h FROM HealthCheck h JOIN FETCH h.tasks t WHERE h.healthCheckid = :id")
    Optional<HealthCheck> getFullHealthCheck(@Param("health_check_id") Long id);

}
```

In plain english, I want to get a specific `HealthCheck` and the associated id of Task. If any of the extended classes of `PIT` `MEM` XMIT` are also present (in there own tables) they will share the same Id as task (in the above query it would be t.id). Part of the answer is to do with TYPE in the query like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71723116/i-want-to-implement-inheritance-strategytable-per-class-using-discriminator-co).

How can I include fields from the child classes like `PIT` where there is a record?

Comment: If you are checking the resulted JSON then you will not see the list of tasks. It is annotated with JsonBackReference.

Comment: PS: for the inheritance type TABLE_PER_CLASS no discriminator column needed. Only for SINGLE_TABLE

Comment: I was getting Jackson error without the JsonBackReference - how do I retrieve it then?

Comment: What error exactly?

Comment: Looks like infinite recursion when I remove BackReference and Managed Reference.

Comment: Yes. You have a bi-directional relationship. But maybe you can mark another end of relationship as JsonBackReference and this one as JsonManagedReference? Would it be an option?

Comment: Can you try the above solution? If you get the appropriate type of task in the result? (I would rather stick with SO communication and provide a proper answer).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by other end of the relationship.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254114/discussion-between-mar-z-and-al-grant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have discussed it on chat and I was able to reproduce your settings. There are some issues with your code:

1. The `@JsonBackReference` annotation in the `HealthCheck` entity cause the field `tasks` to not being serialized. Hence not present in JSON at all. You should swap both annotations around like this:

```
// in HealthCheck
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="healthCheck")
private List<Task> tasks;
// in Task
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private HealthCheck healthCheck;
```

2. You have a field named `healthCheck` not only in the `Task` entity but also in the `PIT` entity. With different meaning. As this field is in use for mapping of tasks this cause an issue while Hibernate is fetching and mapping the entities. Most probably you don't need the second field. Either remove or rename it.
3. For the inheritance type TABLE_PER_CLASS no discriminator column needed. Only for SINGLE_TABLE
4. It is also important to have a proper data in the database. For the minimal test case you should have following entries:

```
Table HEALTH_CHECK: (health_check_id)
(1)
Table TASK: empty! (you have no entities of type Task)
Table PIT: (task_id, health_check_id)
(1, 1)
(2, 1)
```

This means two PITs (with ID 1 and 2) related to the HEALTH_CHECK with ID=1.

Comment: One question : does the task table actually serve any purpose - the model as you have setup does what I require, but is task not needed? (I do need to know all different events that happen under a health check)

Comment: That table is only needed for Hibernate to serve the chosen inheritance type TABLE_PER_CLASS. There are 3 other types supported and each has its advantages and drawbacks. Check this comprehensive guide: https://thorben-janssen.com/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/ or https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-entity-inheritance-with-jpa-and-hibernate/